# How to catch a 403 forbidden error in JS?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to hack a little this facebook javascript code to make a call on an other js if the GET failed.

I have something like this :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/yi_YI/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=###";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="###" data-num-posts="10" data-width="646"></div>
```

Which give a 403 Forbidden (`/*  Not a valid locale.  */`). When it does something like this, I want to be able to load the en_US facebook sdk. So, I have tried :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/yi_YI/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=###";
  try { fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }
  catch(err) {
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=###";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="###" data-num-posts="10" data-width="646"></div>
```

But, it doesn't work, keep getting 403 Forbidden, like if the `try` and `catch(err)` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the HTTP response status of a cross-domain request.

The reason you're getting a 403 is because Facebook doesn't support `yi_YI` as a locale – you will **always** get a 403.  The locale you request must be on the [list of supported locales](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml).

Comment: Since it's an XML doc, it'd be pretty easy to poll against prior to trying to load an unloadable locale.

Comment: @DMCS, true.  I guess it depends whether you're dynamically generating or hardcoding the SDK's URL with locale.  In the latter case, you just need to make sure the locale you want to use is available.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've been doing by hand the supported locales by fb, arg what a lost of time!

Answer (score 0):

use onerror method for script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/yi_YI/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=###";

  //handle loading error 
  js.onerror = function(){alert("script loading error")};

  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="###" data-num-posts="10" data-width="646"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE < 9.  Also, a `onerror` handler doesn't differentiate between a 403 and any other errors (such as network problems or content filters blocking Facebook).